# How would the 20 most powerful Earth governments react to aliens fuzing Mercury and Venus with Mars, then cooling, terraforming, and colonizing it?

Tags: society, aliens, government, earth, terraforming

How would the 20 most powerful Earth governments react to aliens fuzing Mercury and Venus with Mars, then cooling, terraforming, and colonizing it?

They appear from nowhere, and with the use of highly advanced gravitational technology and teleporters, pull Venus and Mercury from their orbits and fuze them with Mars collision-style, saving the debris and atmosphere from being lost in space but rendering Nu Mars completely molten. They stabilize its orbit and rotation, then after sufficiently cooling the surface and atmosphere, they terraform it using samples of Earth species.

They broadcast their intentions to do so beforehand, as well as making it clear that not only do they not want Earth, they consider humans too primitive to currently deal with and have no interest in letting Earthlings settle anywhere on their creation.

Comment: I suspect this may be Opinion Based or Too Broad : Denmark will react differently than Argentina, et al.

Comment: @JDługosz is this better?

Comment: You might be interested in my [extensive Lessons](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4877/lessons-in-writing-questions) on composing questions.  Welcome to WB — I hope we here more from you.

Comment: @JDługosz♦ yes, thank you :) it seems I'm going to have to work on this one a bit more ^^; actually, a lot

Comment: Amazing how well some of those fit you, isn’t it?! My analysis explains why it’s so common to see brain-dump+my-question-is… , and lack of abstraction.  Maybe I'll see you in [chat] sometime.

Comment: I wonder why aliens would make a planet and terraform to be it perfectly habitable for humans, but not allowing humans to go there, instead making the planet habitable for themselves. Wicked sense of humour? I mean, even if the planet could be habitable for both species because they are sufficiently similar, why use Earht's plants and animals instead the alien's original planet species?

Comment: Compare size and nuclear power of said 20 countries with power needed to change orbit of just one of those planets. Realize we are not even near such power.

Comment: A little tip for the future: We have a [Sandbox](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4835/sandbox-for-proposed-questions) on [meta] where you can test a question before releasing it onto the main site. There you can get feedback from others on general stuff, such as on-topic/off-topic, grammar, possible duplicates, missing information, ... Also, if you haven't already done so and have a moment to spare please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to learn more about the site and its scope. Have fun!

Comment: They would demand lower taxes for the rich, and massive video surveillance everywhere. While that wouldn't help, it never had, and was always the answer, no matter what the question was.

Comment: @Rekesoft might be doing it just for lulz, or because their arkship only had enough room for members of their own species and their requisite genebanks to preserve their own genetic diversity. ...Then again, the humans of Earth are the ones they're keeping off, maybe it a 'Piss us off and you go extinct. Don't worry, though. Nobody else will.' Maybe their biology is close enough to the dominant Earth pattern (carbon based, oxygen breathing, water required, helix DNA) that they can do that without trouble. Maybe their own biosphere samples were damaged en-route. I haven't decided on a reason.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Never let fear get in the way of greed.  The Earth government leaders didn't get to where they are by showing any caution or common sense.  Even as the intelligent and scientifically savvy portion of humanity cowers in terror and wonderment at the scale of power these aliens display, our leaders would be boastfully filling the airwaves with invitations to parlay and offers of favorable trading nation status, as if such things might matter to the gods who just moved in next door.  Among all the pomp and flamboyant posturing, the American President, being more business minded than most, would include an invoice for the Earth genetic resources which these new illegal aliens had purloined during their property grab.

When their invitation, offers and overdue notices are inevitably ignored, our wonderful leaders would take offense, demanding of their scientific advisers create the means for swift military retaliation.  Declarations of War would be signed on live television.  We must teach the newcomers whose boss!  Old-time battle hymns would begin to play.

But those scientists, who came to their offices through much more learned paths than their bosses, are not so quick to take offense, especially when global annihilation is on the line.  They would energetically try to convince their masters...

Please don't invoke Armageddon!
They just created a planet!
They are way out of our league!

Then, once their urgent pleas failed, they would quietly poison their bosses and start the first sensible government that our world has ever known.

Turning their eyes away from the strange and new arrangement of stars, out of respect for the beings who rearranged them, the Scientist-Leaders would start trying to figure out what can be learned from what they watched the aliens do.

"Obviously, some of our previous theories are wrong.  Conservation of energy and the insulating effects of vacuum have just been disproven.  But conservation of mass holds up because the combination of those three planets is just about perfectly Earth sized."

"How did it cools so quickly?"

"Where did all the energy to move the planets come from?  Where did all the energy from the melting and merging go as the planet cooled off?"

With these issues and questions as a starting point, our new leadership would apply the entire planet's bounty to continuing our exploration of the universe and its laws.  All this, in the hopes that someday we might become advanced enough to be of interest to the beings who now live next door.

Comment: This makes so much sense it is impossible not to give it a plus one. Enough to make me want to take a bottle of poison and visit my nearest political leader. There's nothing like a bit of preemptive action.

Comment: Long live the Honourable and Providential Guild of Scientific Assassins! +1.

Answer (score 4):

1) First, they would wet their collective pants.

2) Having recovered from that, they would realize that there is nothing they can do. Among other things, all the larger countries are signatories to the Outer Space Treaty, which among other things prohibits any country from laying claim to the moon or any planet. With no country claiming the planets, no country can complain when the aliens do so.

Furthermore, the ability to move the planets so as to combine them establishes that the aliens can squash us like bugs if we annoy them too much. Can you say "Orbital Kinetic Weapon"? Can you say "Dinosaur Killer"? I knew you could.

Answer (score 1):

Basically the majority of nations would come together and once they compare notes realize there is nothing they can do. Especially since their scientific advisers will be saying there is nothing humans can do against such overwhelming power.

Act against the aliens and they might drop the Moon on our heads. What they would have to start doing is begin planning for the long-term. How does the human species accommodate itself to living next door to a hypertechnological civilization? Can we go out into the solar system without upsetting the neighbours? Will humans be allowed to do so?

A form of collective planetary governance will need to be set to try and communicate with the aliens and negotiate a mutual position between humans and the aliens -- if we are allowed to have one.

Probably the best course of action may be to keep a low profile. Try to communicate with the aliens in the hope they will speak to microbes like humans. Organize the infrastructure  for the research and development to build a fleet of spaceships and space stations (both orbital and Moon-based) so we can a foothold on circumterrestrian space. Consideration will be given to constructing deep bunkers in case, for example, the Moon drops on our heads.

Generally the policy will be nice the new neighbours. It seems reasonable that Earth's governments will realize their only option will be to work together collectively. No single nation on the planet will have the resources or the manpower to do anything effective (no matter how impotent that will be in relation to the alien's superior technology). There is little else they can do.

Comment: Minor nitpick: If the moon collided with Earth, it would probably melt the entire crust. You couldn't build a bunker deep enough..

Comment: @AndrewDodds I never said I believed deep bunkers would work. I'm sure they wouldn't. Humans often build things that won't work. We like our security blankets. Something to do with the feel-good factor. The OP's scenario leaves humanity in a state of total impotent relative to the aliens. Building bunkers would be a displacement activity.

Comment: @AndrewDodds. I forget: your nitpick isn't a nitpick. My guess is people would still build them anyway. And as for melting the entire crust, yeah, very likely.